# What is the probability that a cube lands directly on one of its faces?

Tags: probability, geometry, probability-theory

I've been thinking about this problem for a few days. If you had a cube and dropped it, what is the probability that it lands on one of its faces? My initial guess was 3/180 since in each 180 arc rotation of the cube you encounter three faces. I also don't think that is right - if you are half a degree off, then it hasn't technically landed on one of its faces.

So if you are considering half degrees now, there are 360 half degrees in a 180 turn of the cube, of which 3 will suffice. So now instead of 3/180, its 3/360 (smaller).

If you follow this pattern, you will get an infinitely small chance that it lands on one of its faces.. but that doesn't seem right either.

Comment: Indeed, there is an infinitely small chance that if you rotate a cube randomly (in a uniform way, which can be made precise), that one of its faces will be exactly aligned face down; however, in practice gravity will almost certainly lead to it being unstable when it hits the ground, and it will tip to be flat.

Comment: To put it another way, when you toss a die though the air in order to roll it, the probability is practically 100% that one of the corners of the die will hit the table before any other corner does.

Comment: In general if every outcome has the same probability of occurring, there are infinitely many possible outcomes, and you want to know the probability that some finite set of outcomes will have the answer is zero. You can even have infinitely many possibilities and have zero chance such as the probability of picking a rational number out of the reals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The probability is indeed 0. Stated in a different way, you're asking about the event that a random rotation of a cube results in a face being exactly parallel to the ground. This is  a measure $0$ event, meaning the probability is $0$.

Your intuition is correct. Consider an easier problem where you randomly spin a line in a 2D plane. The probability that the line makes an $\leq \epsilon$ angle with the x-axis is $\frac{\epsilon}{\pi}$, which goes to $0$ as $\epsilon \to 0$.